What kind of nuance does のがな gives at the end of a sentence?

I fundamentally understand 教師陣と会話しないといけなくなる which can be "I gotta get conduct a convo with the other teachers otherwise it's no good" but what does  のがな here actually add in term of nuance?  がな I've seen used but the の is giving me pause

I'm pretty sure this is just nominalizing の, such that the が is a subject marker for an unspoken sentence (rather than a connective to an another unspoken sentence). But I don't think it really changes the nuance. At any rate, this should have the [tag:nuances] tag, so I'll add that.

の is a nominalizer, が right after it is a subject marker, and な after it is a sentence-end particle.

教師陣と会話しないといけなくなる
I will need to talk with the teaching staff
教師陣と会話しないといけなくなるの
(the fact) that I will need to talk with the teaching staff
教師陣と会話しないといけなくなるのがな…
(The fact) that I will need to talk with the teaching staff is, ugh...

Something like "(is) the problem" or "(is) the annoying part" is implied after it.
